# GitLab does not work with key loaded in Pageant?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, ssh-keys, atlassian-sourcetree

I keep most of my personal projects on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) by Atlassian. As a natural choice, I use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) app (their product) as git GUI client on Windows, and I'm happy with it. For projects where `ssh` git is available, I prefer `ssh` over `https`. SourceTree plays very well with projects hosted on BitBucket. Although it offers both of ssh agents: OpenSSH or PuTTY, its default selection is PuTTY/Plink (perhaps because PuTTY is more Windows-familiar).

Recently my establishment requested to host some projects on its own server. At first look it's a git server using GitLab opensource. I can use SourceTree with project hosted here using `https` just fine, however when it comes to `ssh`, the only choice of SSH agent is OpenSSH. The only key pair it would use (unless specified in config) is `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (located in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\`

I've tried to:

- Load `~/.ssh/id_rsa` into PuTTY Key Generator
- Convert it to PuTTY format (`.ppk`) file
- Load the `.ppk` into Pageant (PuTTY authentication agent).

Despite the key being loaded and kept in the memory by Pageant, the connection with the server failed all the time, e.g. `git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository`. The only way to make it work is to start `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` (go with OpenSSH).

Since I have Pageant running usually in the background, I find it more convenient to use (e.g. the keyphrase to open the private key is long/complex, and I don't remember it, and it can be copy-pasted from KeePass, while in the case of OpenSSH, `cmd` console does not allow me to paste it, too bad).

Is there anyway to make the ssh authentication to GitLab done via PuTTY instead of OpenSSH?

Answer (score 3):

Did you connect to the SSH server using [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) before using plink? If not a reason could be that plink is refusing to connect to the server, because the ssh hostkey isn't verified yet. Another reason could be that the SSH server requires ciphers which are not supported by PuTTY. You can only find out if you connect with PuTTY with the same version as plink.

Use TortoiseGitPlink (from [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org)) to circumvent this issue, as it will popup a messagebox asking whether to accept the hostkey or not.